# How to call a created class in a test class in java?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. I created a public class called Student and I have also created a test class for it. The thing is I don't know how to call my created class "Student",  inside of the Test class. I have placed both classes in the same folder, yet the Test class is giving out errors saying.

```
TestStudent.java
setName cannot be resolved or is not a field
setPhoneNum cannot be resolved or is not a field
setCgpa cannot be resolved or is not a field
setSubject cannot be resolved or is not a field
setAddress cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

Here is my code for Student class:

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int phoneNum;
    private double cgpa;
    private String subject;
    private String address;

    //getters
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public int getPhoneNum(){
        return phoneNum;
    }

    public double getCgpa(){
        return cgpa;
    }

    public String getSubject(){
        return subject;
    }

    public String getAddress(){
        return address;
    }


    //setters
    public void setName (String newName){
        this.name = newName;
    }

    public void setPhoneNum (int newPhoneNum){
        this.phoneNum = newPhoneNum;
    }

    public void setCgpa (double newCgpa){
        this.cgpa = newCgpa;
    }

    public void setSubject (String newSubject){
        this.subject = newSubject;
    }

    public void setAddress (String newAddress){
        this.address = newAddress;
    }
    
}
```

Here is my code for TestStudent class:

```
public class TestStudent {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Student Alex = new Student();
        Alex.setName = "Alexis";
        Alex.setPhoneNum = 193;
        Alex.setCgpa = 4.0;
        Alex.setSubject = "English, Biology";
        Alex.setAddress = "Rainbow Land";

        System.out.println(Alex.getName());


    }
}
```

Could anyone guide me on this?

Comment: `setName` is a method not an instance field so you should call it as a method invocation `Alex.setName("alexis")`.
You cannot direct access to the private field `name`.
I think you should learn a bit more about the concept of `encapsulation in Java`. The first link I found: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/encapsulation-in-java/

Comment: @nana set the answer as accepted if it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `TestStudent` class should look like this:

```
public class TestStudent {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Student Alex = new Student();
        Alex.setName("Alexis");
        Alex.setPhoneNum(193);
        Alex.setCgpa(4.0);
        Alex.setSubject("English, Biology");
        Alex.setAddress("Rainbow Land");

        System.out.println(Alex.getName());
    }
}
```

You create an `Student` object and then call the setters with the argument in the brackets. There is no assigning with `=` at all. This is done inside of the setter methods.

Comment: my bad, i fixed it earlier but didn't save when i reopen-ed the file. I'll update it here. Thanks for pointing that out.